# Live template for doc style comments in PhpStorm

Tags: comments, phpstorm

How to set a live template in PhpStorm so that when I hit enter for a new line, it automatically adds an asterisk? Or maybe there is another way to do it, e.g. wrap with comments action?

```
/**
 * More sensible default box-sizing:
 * css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice
 */
```